# How can I display how many Facebook "likes" a page has in Drupal?

Tags: facebook, drupal

In drupal I want to show the amount of likes our page has.

I know you can use the facebook graph utility, but i don't know how to put in correct code, for a html "snippet". Anyone some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Drupal - but this is how you would do it via HTML + JS:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB._https = true;
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : YOUR APP ID, // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : 'channel.html', // YOUR CHANNEL HTML
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true, 
      xfbml      : true 
    });

    getPage();

};
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false))


getPage = function() {
    var pageID = 'http://google.com';  //put your site here
    var pageUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+pageID;
    FB.api(pageUrl, 'get', function(response) {
            alert( response.likes )
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PHP snippet in a block or any other place you are allowed to use php:

```
$graph    = 'https://graph.facebook.com/< your facebook page id>/?fields=likes';
$response = file_get_contents($graph);
$json     = json_decode($response);
try {
  if (!isset($json->likes)) {
    throw new Exception('Like count not found in facebook graph object');
  }
  $likes = $json->likes;
  // do something with $likes
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to enable "php code" text filter, create node and choose "php format", than in node body put updated Arlina's code:

```
$graph    = 'https://graph.facebook.com/< your facebook page id>/?fields=likes&access_token=< your application access_token >';
$response = file_get_contents($graph);
$json     = json_decode($response);
try {
if (!isset($json->likes)) {
    throw new Exception('Like count not found in facebook graph object');
}
$likes = $json->likes;
  echo $likes;
} catch (Exception $e) {
// handle error
}
```

finally save the node.